# an issue in Assembly using Emu 8086 , jump not working

Tags: assembly, x86-16

i just start on making my project for university for  flipping card game, 
using emulator from emu8086.com

sadly i got stuck on such a early stat .

somehow can't quite figure out whats wrong .

the jump using JZ or JE , should work if i use cmp on 2 equal value , but it is not working .

nothing happening ! i used

```
mov ah,1
int 21h

cmp al,1 or cmp al,'1'
JE or JZ  Card1
```

but it is not jumping no matter what i write ,

my full code :

```
include "emu8086.inc"
; multi-segment executable file template.

data segment
     ; add your data here!
     pkey db "press any key...$"  
     data_error dw "input error....    $"
     datar db 0      ;row
     datac db 0      ;cloumn
     datacard db '1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'
     data1 dw ?
     data2 dw ?
     dataf dw "False              $"
     endapp dw "END GAME....              $"
     datat dw "True               $"
     datas db '0'
     score dw "Score : $"
     x db ? 
     y db ?  
     a db '0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'
     data3 db 'D','B','A','O','C','C','A','B','D'

ends

stack segment
    dw   128  dup(0)
ends

code segment
start:
; set segment registers:
    mov ax, data
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax

    ; add your code here

GOTOXY 25,0
;PRINT 'Wellcom to My Flipping Game !?!'
GOTOXY 10, 5      
mov si,offset data3
PUTC [si]
GOTOXY 15, 5
inc si
PUTC [si]
GOTOXY 20, 5
inc si
PUTC [si]
GOTOXY 10, 8
inc si
PUTC [si] 
GOTOXY 15, 8
inc si
PUTC [si]
GOTOXY 20, 8
inc si
PUTC [si]
GOTOXY 10, 11
inc si
PUTC [si]
GOTOXY 15, 11
inc si
PUTC [si]
GOTOXY 20, 11
inc si
PUTC [si] 

GOTOXY 10, 5
mov si,offset datacard
PUTC [si]
GOTOXY 15, 5
inc si
PUTC [si]
GOTOXY 20, 5
inc si
PUTC [si]
GOTOXY 10, 8
inc si
PUTC [si] 
GOTOXY 15, 8
inc si
PUTC [si]
GOTOXY 20, 8
inc si
PUTC [si]
GOTOXY 10, 11
inc si
PUTC [si]
GOTOXY 15, 11
inc si
PUTC [si]
GOTOXY 20, 11
inc si
PUTC [si] 

GOTOXY 25, 15             


Print 'Enter your Selection : '   

mov ah,1
int 21h

mov ah,al

cmp ah,1
JZ card1

cmp ah,2
JE card2

cmp ah,3
JE card3

cmp ah,4
JE card4

cmp ah,5
JE card5

cmp ah,6
JE card6

cmp ah,7
JE card7

cmp ah,8
JE card8

cmp ah,9
JE card9

JMP deadend

card1 :

GOTOXY 10, 5      
mov si,offset data3
PUTC [si]
JMP deadend

card2 :

GOTOXY 15, 5      
mov si,offset data3
inc si
PUTC [si]
JMP deadend

card3 :

GOTOXY 20, 5      
mov si,offset data3
inc si
inc si
PUTC [si]
JMP deadend

card4 :

mov si,offset data3
inc si
inc si
inc si
PUTC [si]
JMP deadend

card5 :

mov si,offset data3
inc si
inc si
inc si
inc si
PUTC [si]
JMP deadend

card6 :

mov si,offset data3
inc si
inc si
inc si
inc si
inc si
PUTC [si]
JMP deadend

card7 :

mov si,offset data3
inc si
inc si
inc si
inc si
inc si
inc si
PUTC [si]
JMP deadend

card8 :

mov si,offset data3
inc si
inc si
inc si
inc si
inc si
inc si
inc si
PUTC [si]
JMP deadend

card9 :

mov si,offset data3
inc si
inc si
inc si
inc si
inc si
inc si
inc si
inc si
PUTC [si]
JMP deadend



deadend:             


    lea dx, pkey
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h        ; output string at ds:dx

    ; wait for any key....    
    mov ah, 1
    int 21h

    mov ax, 4c00h ; exit to operating system.
    int 21h    
ends

end start ; set entry point and stop the assembler.
```

i left the sample codes from making a new file in emulator in my code , will remove them later.

u see i put AL into AH and used it too , just coz i couldn't  figure whats wrong ,
but it didn't work when i used AL itself in cmp either

non of the JE / JZ jumps work , only the JMP one work .

Tnx.

Comment: You should be comparing against `'1'..'9'`, not `1..9`. Anyway, reduce this down to a program where you've removed everything except the code to read a character and print something if the character equals whatever value (let's say `'1'`). That should make it easier for you to find the problem.

Comment: damn net was down for 2 hours , anyway , i did check it with '1' '2' and '9' too , still no result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it , Quite Silly ,

The Problem was just that i was puting an space before : of my lable ! lol

like

```
card1 :
```

..... while it should have been

```
card1:
```

i also change back my code to use AL for everything , and put ' ' on the numbers.